# How can i fix my code to make my count value update from my function

Tags: flutter

How can i make  `_handlerRadioValuegender()`  update my `count` value which I declared as `var count = 3` on top.

I tried what i can do and here are all `debugprint()` functions results. It is now always taking the value which I define on top means my `_handler` function has no effect on the count value.

```
var count = 3;
int _handleRadioValuegender(int value) {
  setState(() {
    _gender = value;

    switch (_gender) {
      case 0:
        debugPrint('case0');
        count++;
        debugPrint('$count');
        break;

      case 1:
        debugPrint('case1');
        this.count++;
        this.count++;
        debugPrint('$count');
        break;
    }
  });
}

String gender() {
  if (count == 1) {
    debugPrint('$count');
    return 'Male';
  } else if (count == 3) {
    debugPrint('$count');
    return 'Female';
  } else {
    debugPrint('$count');
  }
}
```

I want my count value to be updated from my `_handlerRadioValuegender()` function and when `gender()` access it, then it should return value according to that.[Screenshot of debugprints()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVRU6.png)